# Rails 3.0.9 + Ruby 1.9.2 p180 + Devise - Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 3.0.9 + Ruby 1.9.2 p180 + Devise, and here's my routes:

```
[...]
devise_for :users,:controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
[...]
root :to => "users/sessions#new"
```

I basically wanted to make the devise login page my root route... But when I try to it my local server (http://localhost:3000), I get the following error:

```
Unknown action

Could not find devise mapping for path "/". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside
the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => 
"some_devise_controller" end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
devise_scope :user do 
  root :to => "users/sessions#new"
end
```

**Edit:**
if you were using devise's default controllers then you would do this:

```
devise_scope :user do 
  root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Comment: Would `users/` be redundant in this case?

Comment: Depends on how you subclassed the controller. If you have `class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` then you would use just `sessions#new`.

Comment: I will test the above later, but here's what I did (and it seemed to work):
 
    `devise_for :users ,:controllers => { :sessions => 'users/sessions' } do`
        `root :to => "users/sessions#new"
    end`
... This devise_for and devise_scope thing can be quite confusing.

Comment: What's the difference in this case (between devise_for and devise_scope)...?

Comment: It's functionally the same, see [configuring routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: make sure its `devise_scope :user` and not `devise_scope :users`